# Why does this function dont respond?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I am working in a Telegram Bot which gets random numbers from an array and outputs it but there is one else if statement in which one sendMessage function don't respond.
I have many similiar else if statements and they work without any problems.

**The if else statement:**

```
if(strpos($message,"/rand")===0){
 sendMessage($chatId, '<b>Getting a number...</b>');
 sendMessage($chatId,'<b>Number</b>: <i>' .$result. '</i>%0A%0A'); 
 sendMessage($botGroupId,'@'.$username.'/'.$userId. ' has used ' .$message. ' command');
 }
```

The user is not recieving this from the if else statement:

```
  sendMessage($chatId,'<b>Number</b>: <i>' .$result. '</i>%0A%0A');
```

**This is how i get the random number from the array:**

```
include 'randnum.php';//get content from php files --> include the php file...
$getindex_from_array=array_rand($randnumbers); //gen random index 
$result=$randnumbers[$getindex_from_array]; //get a random number from gen index
 //end
```

**This is how i have numbers in array(randnum.php):**

```
<?php
$randnumbers=array("44534","347467","4734856","475348568");
?>
```

Comment: can you add sendMessage code?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you mean the sendMessage function code?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone:    function sendMessage($chatId, $message){ //sendMessage function
$url = $GLOBALS["botwebsite"]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$message."&parse_mode=HTML";
file_get_contents($url);      
}

Comment: is /sendMessage your own endpoint if so your need to show the code? as [this](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/blob/fb55e78e980dfabef4bed606c2385f6897dd2d84/src/Request.php#L482) tried and tested lib, does a POST request to `https://api.telegram.org/bot/<api_key>/sendMessage`, it looks like your doing GET

Comment: you should also [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) all them parameters `?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$message."`

Comment: This is my whole code which do the sendMessage and co .[HERE](https://pastebin.com/tHfMhk6n)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i just checked and realized that the command works like 1-2 times and then it doesnt